# Email spf issues

Tags: postfix-mta, spf, dkim

Not quite sure I understand the problem, but lets say I'm *sending email through **postfix***. I do it from domain a.com, in the email from address is mail@b.com and there's a valis txt dns record at b.com that includes a.com domain. All is well at that point.

The return path is:

```
Return-Path: <a_random_message_id@a.com>
```

And the authentication results:

```
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@b.com header.s=dmnkey header.b=9Rn2RL3X;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of a_random_message_id@a.com designates 1.2.3.4 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=a_random_message_id@a.com
```

Does this mean that *whenever I send an email, the return path domain is checked instead of from email, and then the dns checked for that domain, to validate spf*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, yes. Strictly speaking it's the `MAIL FROM` envelope sender at the SMTP level that is checked - mainly because this can be checked before the message itself even starts to be sent, saving wasted data transfer. The receiving server takes the envelope sender and adds it as a return-path header on the received message - it's not added by the sender.

Comment: So.. This means that it's esentially authenticating my own domains spf not the domain that's at the from address. Can this be fixed so the from email domain is being used to authenticate spf?

Comment: Sure - use your from domain in the envelope sender. This may have side effects though.

Comment: Well ... I do need to parse bounces etc so I can't just change the Return-Path of the email. Are there any alternatives?

Comment: Like I said... side effects! You're probably looking at routing bounces back from mail servers set to handle those other domains. Yes it is messy and difficult...